# jquery .on firing on child elements unexpectedly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I create elements from a JSON call to build a list as follows. Note that msg.id is used to set the id of li.

```
                // create variations on somecharacter_id for id so that clicking upon any element reveals associated message id - see clickedId in .on(....)
                for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    var msg = messages[i];
                    var msgString = '<li id="' + msg.id + '" class="msgbox todo-content"><div class="todo-icon fui-bubble-16"></div><div class="todo-content"><h4 class="todo-name">';
                    msgString += msg.sendfrom;
                    msgString += '</h4>' + msg.subject;
                    msgString += '<div style="font-size:x-small;color:#bdc3c7;">' + parseTime(msg.timestamp_string) + '</div></div></li>';
                    $('#message-list').append(msgString);
                }
```

I wish to retrieve msg.id for the relevant row clicked, so li is given class name .msgbox and I made a .on() event with .msgbox. However, within the li are various divs. When I click on ANYthing within the li, the .on event fires (which I believe is expected behavior). Since the  within the li do not have an id, alert(event.target.id) displays null. Should I add id's to each child element within li to capture the relevant id? Surely there's a better way.

```
 $('.msgbox').on('click', function (event) {                               // example 

                // get id
                var clickedId = event.target.id;

                alert(clickedId);
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
var clickedId = event.target.id;
```

with

```
var clickedId = this.id;
```

You're not interested in the most precise element which was clicked but on the `li` on which you bound the event handler and which was clicked. This element is `this` in the event handler.